# Rails Twilio check National Do Not Call List?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

Has anyone ever found and API or anything to check to see if a number is on the national do not call list before placing an automated call using Twilio?

I've been looking around but have been struggling to find an easy way to access the list.

Comment: I believe you need to register to access that data. Check this out: https://telemarketing.donotcall.gov/

Comment: Ahh you're right. Thanks for the quick response!